# How to change the language of category names in Model Browser of Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Following the sample

https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/localised-languages-for-view-data-api.html

I will be able to adapt the names of toolbar and also the tooltip inside Model Browser, but the category names are still in an unexpected language.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Viewer's language settings only affect the Viewer's own UI.

Category names and other model data are extracted from the model's design file and picked up by Viewer from the model data json files, and hence can't be automatically translated by the language settings.

**UPDATE**

Per Engineering: it is identified by the `last saved Revit language version`. When a German model being opened and saved in English version of Revit, the displayName will be shown in English in Viewer then.

Comment: When I open the model via BIM 360 Document management the categories are listed in English.
Using the same model and open it using my own forge application the categories are listed in German. How can I get the same language in both apps?

Comment: What format is the model? What were your export settings if applicable? Is German your system language?

Comment: The original model is the Revit sample file rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt.
What do you mean by 'export settings'? I did the upload using the BIM 360 Document Management.
Yes, the Windos OS is German. I change the Chrome browser language between  English (US) and German. I need to change the language for the category names depending on browser settings.

Comment: So just to sum up - the model is uploaded to BIM360 and not to a OSS bucket? If you change the language settings in your browser to English would it affect the category names? What I will do is pass these on to Engineering and get their suggestions.

Comment: The model is manually uploaded to BIM360 Document Management. In the meantime, I've found that the current Browser language when uploading the model is that one in which the category names are displayed. Changing the browser language after the upload does not affect the category names language in the Viewers model browser.
Is there a way to customize the language for category names in a similar way, like changing the language of Viewer's UI?

Comment: That behavior is consistent with VIewer's data model where model data is read from the endpoints as is extracted - checking with Engineering to see if there's a way to specify language for model data during extraction.